# include a javascript file only on signup page - Rails & Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I need to include a JS file only on the signup page of my rails application. I am using Turbolinks.

I have the below code in application.html.erb just before the `<head>` section

```
 <%= yield :page_specific%>
```

and below is the code in my `registrations/new.html.erb`

```
<%content_for :page_specific do%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'page_specific/users/registrations/index', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true%>
<%end%>
```

This works as expected and loads the script on the registrations page, but if I visit the login page from registrations page, the script remains included in the head section as i have turbolinks enabled.

How can include a page specific javascript only on signup page with turbolinks enabled.

Comment: Try this: ```<%= yield :page_specific if content_for?(:page_specific) %>``` @opensource-developer

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but how about we include js for all the page normally, but we write our js to run per page, something like this https://medium.com/@cblavier/rails-with-no-js-framework-26d2d1646cd

Comment: Hi @Violeta, that did not work and the reason is with turbolinks enabled, the content of body is dynamically replaced and not the head section

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the most elegant way but I managed to fix the issue by disabling turoblinks on login and sign up link by using `:'data-turbolinks' => "false"`

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just include `javascript_include_tag` into view of target page